# Natural Language Processing Toolkit for .NET

Tags: .net, nlp

Can you give me some toolkits and libraries for natural language processing in .NET.

Are there tools like UIMA for .NET?

Comment: I have successfully created a sample project for newbies. You can get the project from the following link.<br>PS:Please change the nbin file path as your's computer file path. Hope this will help.  

Click [HERE][1] for Sample Project or as below.
 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XcMZLArSF1UURzODRiVmE0RUE/view?usp=sharing


  [1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XcMZLArSF1UURzODRiVmE0RUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: FYI - there is a [whitepaper on UIMA for .NET integration](http://2009.rmll.info/IMG/pdf/FrancoisRegisChaumartin_UIMA_LSM09_paper.pdf) using [Apache IKVM](https://www.ikvm.net/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is  [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/)  ....